# How to make MediaPlayer play music only while my app is in foreground?

Tags: android, android-activity, media-player

I have an app consisting of several activities. I'd like a background music to play continuously while user is navigating between them and stop is user goes to home screen/some other app/locks the screen.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up stopping music after 500ms timeout after onPause if it is not resumed in an onResume of some other activity. If activity switch takes longer than 500ms, then it's perfectly reasonable that music should stop until the next activity loads. And when user presses home button, 500ms delay before stopping music is not noticeable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service to do the same. It is the best way to tun background tasks

Here is a sample service

http://androidcore.com/android-programming-tutorials/638-how-to-use-android-services.html

You can try adding mediaplayer related code here

Comment: The main problem is how to make that service pause when app is in background and destroy when app is destroyed.

Comment: I am not sure if you can pause the player while pressing the home key. As you know Home Key event cannot be overridden for security constraints. When pressing home android just puts your application on the background but still your tasks or services will run. If you have a dummy root activity that doesn't require the application to play music you can try adding android:finishOnTaskLaunch in your manifest to that root activity or you can try setting cleartop flag .

Answer (score 0):

Implement `onPause` and `onResume`. These are called by Android when your activity is sent to the background and when it comes back to the foreground. Use `onStop` to handle when your app is killed by Android and no longer visible or running.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing now, plus this: before transferring control to another activity of my app I raise a special flag "do not kill service on onPause" to avoid interrupting music. But in some cases (e.g. config change) onCreate/onDestroy is called anyway and I can not intercept it to raise that flag. This is why I'm looking for a more general solution.